# Does MISRA C++ rule 7-1-1 affect references?

Tags: c++, reference, misra

> #### Rule 7-1-1 (Required) A variable which is not modified shall be const qualified
>
> If a variable does not need to be modified, then it shall be
>   declared with const qualification so that it cannot be modified. A
>   non-parametric variable will then require its initialization at the
>   point of declaration. Also, future maintenance cannot accidentally
>   modify the value.
>
> ```
> void b ( int32_t * );
> int32_t f (       int32_t * p1,                 // Non-compliant
>                   int32_t * const p2,           // Compliant
>                   int32_t * const p3 )          // Compliant
> {
>      *p1 = 10;
>      *p2 = 10;
>      b( p3 );
>      int32_t i = 0;                             // Non-compliant
>      return i;
> }
> ```

The example included in the standard is focused on pointers. The rule requires all the pointers meeting the conditions to be `const`, e.g. `int * const`. If I understand it correctly, it *does not* require pointers and references to point to `const` objects, e.g. `const int *` or `const int &`. In fact, it is covered by another rule (but only for parameters!):

> Rule 7-1-2 (Required) A pointer or reference parameter in a function shall be declared as pointer to const or reference to const if the corresponding object is not modified

So, does the rule 7-1-1 apply to references at all? A reference cannot be re-bound after it has been created, so it should be treated like a `const` pointer. Therefore all references should automatically comply with the rule 7-1-1.

***EDIT** (based on comments by [Lightness Races in Orbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit), [Richard Critten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3370124/richard-critten) & [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4706785/peter) and my experiments):* Or does the rule apply to the type of referenced object in the case of references? I mean `const int &` vs. `int &` similarly to `const int` vs. `int`?
I am asking because my MISRA C++ checker keeps reporting violations on references… Example of its behavior:

```
class A
{
    int property;
public:
    A(int param) : property(param) {}     // violation: should be: const int param
    int get_property() const { return property; }
    void set_property(int param) { property = param; }  // violation: should be: const int param
};

class ConstA
{
    const int property;
public:
    ConstA(int param) : property(param) {}  // violation: should be: const int param
    int get_property() const { return property; }
    // setter not allowed
};

void example1()
{
    const A const_obj_A(1);
    A nonconst_obj_A(2);
    ConstA nonconst_obj_constA(3);      // OK: used to create a non-const reference
    const A& const_ref_A = nonconst_obj_A;
    A& nonconst_ref_A = nonconst_obj_A; // OK: setter called
    nonconst_ref_A.set_property(4);
    ConstA& const_ref_constA = nonconst_obj_constA; // violation: no modification
    // In fact, it seems to be impossible to make
    // a non-violating ConstA& declaration.
    // The only chance is to make another non-const reference
    // but the last declaration in the chain will still violate.
}

void example2()
{
    const A const_obj_A(1);
    A nonconst_obj_A(2);
    ConstA nonconst_obj_constA(3);      // violation: used only in const reference
    const A& const_ref_A = nonconst_obj_A;
    A& nonconst_ref_A = nonconst_obj_A; // violation: no modification using the ref.
    const ConstA& const_ref_constA = nonconst_obj_constA;
}
```

Comment: It says "variable" so my take is if a reference could be made const it should be.

Comment: If your question is about references then please provide the code in question with references. ... IMHO this rule is very weak.

Answer (score 5):

No, 7-1-1 does not apply to references.

A declaration of the form `int32_t & const p2` is nonsense.

The only meaningful `const` qualification of a refeence is of the form `const int32_t &p2` or the equivalent `int32_t const &p2`.   Then need for these forms is covered completely in 7-1-2.

Misra 7-1-1 doesn't need to apply to such references because the philosophy of Misra is to specify constraints that the language standard does not, not to restate constraints already specified in the language (and enforced by compilers).   Misra 7-1-1 requires a variable (say, of type `int32_t`) to be declared `const` if it will not be modified - such as `i` in the quoted example.   In standard C++, it is not possible to create a non-`const` reference to that variable - unless a type conversion (aka "cast") is used to remove the `const`ness.   Misra rule 5-2-5 requires that such casts shall not be used.

Comment: Almost but not quite - 7-1-2 only covers parameters, unless there is text that the OP did not quote

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are right. The rule 7-1-2 says: _This rule leads to greater precision in the definition of the function interface._ So it does not affect local variables. This makes the 7-1-1 even more questionable…

Comment: @Melebius: Even stranger, it goes on to state that it means the pointee should be `const`, not the pointer itself. Which is just baffling. Much like with the Google C++ style guide, I take issue with those that insist upon sticking to MISRA "rules" as if they were law. Or, well, as if they were sensible.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for comments, I’ve refined the question.

Comment: Misra doesn't generally state requirements that are part of the language.   If an object is `const`, which 7-1-1 would require if the intent is not to modify it, then it is not possible in C++ to create a non-`const` reference to it unless a type conversion (aka "cast") is used to remove the `const` qualifier.  A C++ compiler would diagnose an error.   While it is possible to bludgeon the compiler into submission with a type conversion, another Misra rule (5-2-5) requires that such casts shall not be used.   I'll edit and add a comment to that effect shortly.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for the addition. However, this is not what I meant. I added an example to my question to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

There is significant semantic difference between C++ pointer and reference: reference is NOT an object (variable).

It's just object alias. So by strict formal meaning 7-1-1 shall not be applied to references.

Comment: And, even if it were relevant, it would apply implicitly as the question already states. So yeah can't see how 7-1-1 applies. 7-2-2 is the relevant rule but, oddly, only applies to function params

Comment: Agree, rules are a bit vague. 7-1-1 is about variables, but the sample depicts function parameters. It's not clear does "variable" term actually includes params and what is the purpose of distinguish them in 7-1-2.